# Get Injected module property after promise

Tags: ecmascript-6, aurelia

Aurelia FW:
I have a module with a property that being set by a service promise in the activate event:

```
this.httpService.get("Demo").then(response => { this.userAccountsData = 
response; this.numberOfAccounts = this.userAccountsData.length; })
```

I use that module in the app.html as composition:

```
<compose view-    
model="./resources/usersAccountsCollection/usersAccountsCollection">
</compose>
```

and I inject that modlue into app.js and get its properties in the constructor in order to check them:

```
export class App {
constructor(accounts) {
this.usersAccounts = accounts;
```

The problem is that I receive the value before the promise (numberOfAccounts = 0). I would like to get their value after the promise (after the data returns). I'm quite sure that if I would get them in the app.js activate event it would be good, but how I inject the nodule or its property as aparameter into the activate function ?

Comment: Based on the questions you have asked so far, it really would behoove you to go watch Brian Noyes's Pluralsight course on Aurelia. There's a fair amount of basic Aurelia concepts you are having trouble with. Here's a link to the course: https://www.pluralsight.com/courses/aurelia-fundamentals

Comment: @Ashley, thanks.
I intend doing that. Meanwhile - it is on job training

Comment: Well, most of what you've asked so far can be found in our docs. I would start with the cheat sheet: http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/framework/latest/cheat-sheet